# SQL server table to HTML table with pivoting

Tags: javascript, php, sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to make a SQL server table display pivoted in HTML using PHP.

The columns of the HTML table would be the content of the "CONCEPT" column of the SQL table and the content of the HTML columns would be the result of the "DATA" column of the SQL.

Not all records have the same number of "columns" that is, for example the serial number 12345 has the RAM column but the serial number 67890 does not, so the HTML table cell should appear as blank.

This is the tab delimited file: https://pastebin.com/sFJEHJLm

[image]

All the concepts of each article have a record with the same value as "LINE", but I don't know how to take advantage of this data to make the painting of the table.

I have tried to load each of the SQL columns in different PHP arrays and then cycle through the array by painting the HTML table but, at the moment a serial number that has a column arrives, the relationship of the results in the HTML table is lost With the correct column.

```
if ($_REQUEST['accion'] == "abrir_auditoria") {

    $array_titulos = array();
    $Total = 0;
    $Actual = 0;

    try
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM AUDITORIAS_LIN WHERE AUDITORIA = '" . $_REQUEST['id'] . "'";

        $q = $pdo->query($sql);
        $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while ($r = $q->fetch()):

            if (!in_array(htmlspecialchars($r['CONCEPTO']), $array_titulos))
            {
                array_push($array_titulos, htmlspecialchars($r['CONCEPTO']));
            }

        endwhile;

        echo "<table border=1>";
            echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($array_titulos as $titulo)
                {
                    echo "<th>$titulo</th>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";

            $q = $pdo->query($sql);
            $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $Total = key(array_slice($array_titulos, -1, 1, true));

            while ($r = $q->fetch()):
                if ($Total != $Actual)
                {
                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($r['DATO']) . "</td>";
                    $Actual++;
                } else {
                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($r['DATO']) . "</td>";
                    $Actual = 0;
                }
            endwhile;

            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";

    }
    catch(PDOException $pe)
    {
        die("database connect error：". $pe->getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: You can try PIVOT to prepare data using MSSQL query. We can help further if you provide some expected output data considering given sample data. Also please replace sample data with text/tabular data as image do not help if any testing is required regarding data.

Comment: The PIVOT method directly on the SQL query is not supported by server compatibility. In addition, I cannot change the compatibility of the server since it could affect the rest of the software that is using this database.

Comment: pivot should be supported buy server. What is your sql server version and competiability mode?

Comment: The compatibility mode is 80 "SQL Server 2000".

And, this is the tab delimited file: https://pastebin.com/sFJEHJLm